# Ubuntu occasionally freezes after extensive hard drive activity in Firefox. Logs show many CRON records at about the same time

Tags: cron, freeze

After a few hours in Firefox, the hard drive begins to be very active, and display progress slows until system becomes overloaded.  Sometimes I can wait it out, but more often I have to press reset to regain control. I found this section in the log:

```
Feb 28 16:13:49 roger-desktop PackageKit: uid 1000 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
Feb 28 16:15:48 roger-desktop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Feb 28 16:15:48 roger-desktop pkexec[4324]: roger: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/roger] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Feb 28 16:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[4339]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 16:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[4339]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 16:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[4421]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 16:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[4421]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 16:48:49 roger-desktop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Feb 28 16:48:49 roger-desktop pkexec[4584]: roger: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/roger] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Feb 28 17:09:48 roger-desktop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Feb 28 17:09:48 roger-desktop pkexec[6851]: roger: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/roger] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Feb 28 17:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[7136]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 17:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[7136]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 17:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[7555]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 17:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[7555]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 18:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[7667]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 18:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[7667]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 18:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[7823]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 18:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[7823]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 19:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[9477]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 19:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[9477]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 19:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[9530]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 19:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[9530]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 20:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[10413]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 20:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[10413]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 20:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[11468]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 20:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[11468]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 21:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[12234]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 21:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[12234]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 21:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[12695]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 21:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[12695]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 22:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[13958]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 22:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[13958]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 22:30:02 roger-desktop CRON[14157]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 22:30:02 roger-desktop CRON[14157]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 23:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[15329]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 23:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[15329]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 23:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[15356]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 23:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[15356]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 00:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[16053]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 00:17:03 roger-desktop CRON[16053]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 01:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[17063]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 01:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[17063]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 01:18:01 roger-desktop CRON[17067]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 01:18:01 roger-desktop CRON[17067]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 02:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[17381]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 02:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[17381]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 03:10:01 roger-desktop CRON[18324]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 03:10:01 roger-desktop CRON[18324]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 03:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[18642]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 03:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[18642]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 04:17:03 roger-desktop CRON[21156]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 04:17:05 roger-desktop CRON[21156]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 04:22:13 roger-desktop systemd-logind[1303]: System is powering down.
Mar  1 18:38:20 roger-desktop systemd-logind[1316]: New seat seat0.
Mar  1 18:38:20 roger-desktop systemd-logind[1316]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
Mar  1 18:38:20 roger-desktop systemd-logind[1316]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Mar  1 18:38:20 roger-desktop systemd-logind[1316]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event3 (Logitech K350)
Mar  1 18:38:45 roger-desktop lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Mar  1 18:38:45 roger-desktop systemd-logind[1316]: New session c1 of user lightdm.
Mar  1 18:38:45 roger-desktop systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Mar  1 18:38:46 roger-desktop lightdm: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly
Mar  1 18:38:59 roger-desktop lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "roger"
Mar  1 18:39:08 roger-desktop lightdm: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Mar  1 18:39:08 roger-desktop lightdm: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Mar  1 18:39:08 roger-desktop lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user roger by (uid=0)
Mar  1 18:39:08 roger-desktop systemd-logind[1316]: New session c2 of user roger.
Mar  1 18:39:08 roger-desktop systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user roger by (uid=0)
Mar  1 18:39:08 roger-desktop systemd-logind[1316]: Removed session c1.
Mar  1 18:39:11 roger-desktop lightdm: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
Mar  1 18:39:12 roger-desktop dbus-daemon[1268]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Mar  1 18:39:21 roger-desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[2145]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Mar  1 18:39:29 roger-desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[2145]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Mar  1 18:39:29 roger-desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[2145]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
Mar  1 18:39:31 roger-desktop polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.93 [/usr/bin/gnome-flashback], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Mar  1 18:39:46 roger-desktop dbus-daemon[1268]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Mar  1 18:40:45 roger-desktop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar  1 18:40:45 roger-desktop pkexec[3380]: roger: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/roger] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Mar  1 18:40:49 roger-desktop PackageKit: uid 1000 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh auth (only_trusted:0)
Mar  1 18:40:49 roger-desktop PackageKit: uid 1000 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
Mar  1 18:41:41 roger-desktop PackageKit: uid 1000 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh auth (only_trusted:0)
Mar  1 18:41:41 roger-desktop PackageKit: uid 1000 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
Mar  1 18:43:38 roger-desktop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar  1 18:43:38 roger-desktop pkexec[5867]: roger: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/roger] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Mar  1 19:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[7689]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 19:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[7689]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 19:22:46 roger-desktop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar  1 19:22:46 roger-desktop pkexec[7856]: roger: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/roger] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Mar  1 19:30:02 roger-desktop CRON[8054]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 19:30:02 roger-desktop CRON[8054]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 20:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[11322]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 20:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[11322]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 20:30:02 roger-desktop CRON[11817]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 20:30:02 roger-desktop CRON[11817]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 21:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[13444]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 21:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[13444]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 21:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[13908]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 21:30:02 roger-desktop CRON[13908]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 22:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[14997]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 22:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[14997]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 22:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[15801]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 22:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[15801]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 23:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[17004]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 23:17:01 roger-desktop CRON[17004]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  1 23:30:01 roger-desktop CRON[17337]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  1 23:30:02 roger-desktop CRON[17337]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  2 00:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[19193]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  2 00:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[19193]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  2 01:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[22122]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  2 01:17:02 roger-desktop CRON[22122]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar  2 01:18:24 roger-desktop CRON[22160]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  2 01:18:32 roger-desktop CRON[22160]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: You've not provided any OS/product/release details, what are you running?   As you believe it's in firefox, I'd check what extensions etc. you've added & given permission to run in the background within `firefox`; though for some releases I used to have issues with memory-leaks due to some extensions (*i had no issues if I stopped using them, but didn't want not to so used them & just recognized the issue & dealt with it; later releases dealt with OOM differently*) but without release details we're somewhat limited

Comment: It’s normal behaviour for cron to check to see if there is any work to do quite frequently. It can check on the hour for hourly, daily, weekly and monthly tasks and then run them with a random gap of typically 20 minutes. I don’t think cron is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

PROBABLE solution:

1. Check in Firefox Sttings, General, Performance
2. Try recommended performance settings (mine was off)
3. Immediately Reboot Firefox and Entire System.
4. Check if ok now.

Last two days seem much better for me, need more run time to be sure.